# Transferring data and formulas from google sheets to MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I have a database with multiple worksheet in google sheets. I have noticed that google sheets is not efficient to record the transactions. So I would like to copy all the formulas and data in google sheets to mysql database and link it to a web app. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'copy', but generally things are doable

Comment: @Strawberry https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit?usp=sharing - This is the link to my google sheets. Can I just transfer everything in that google sheets?

Comment: I doubt you can do it in precisely the way you imagine. I suspect some manual re-engineering will be required.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you so much for your advice. Actually, I dont have the idea of how mysql works. I just want to learn things now that is why I asked you here. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*It is not possible to do it in a simple way*

### Where to start?

This problem has two fields of study, on the one hand connecting Apps Script with MySQL and on the other hand how to create tables and populate them in MySQL. I attach a couple of links so you can start to have a look and get an idea of where to start to face the challenge.

### References

- [Apps Scipt: external database via JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)
- [W3Schools: MySQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/)